# How to dont get webdriver detected?

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver, bots

today i wrote my first Python Script with Selenium. When I use the Chrome or the Edge webdriver I alway get a little banner, saying, that I'm using a webdriver. So it's getting detected. Many sites block these or don't allow them do make anything on the site. Is there any easy way don't get the driver not get detected?

Thanks

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from tkinter import *

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(path)

driver.get("https://youtube.de")
print(driver.title)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please edit the question and clarify the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Save chromedriver.exe in the work directory.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless') #If you need HeadLess mod
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    browser.get(link)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how can I get the path in it now. If I put it the options=options I get an error.

Comment: options(argument) = options(class instance)